# Where dataframe 1 equals x change dataframe y

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

the first:

```
a = {'Price': [10, 15, 20, 25, 30], 'Total': [10000, 12000, 10000, 11000, 10000],
     'Previous Quarter': [9000, 10000, 12000, 15000, 14000]}
a = pd.DataFrame(a)
print (a)
```

the second is:

```
b = {'Price': [0, 94, 82, 16, 31], 'Total': [0, 900, 11000, 11000, 14000],
     'Previous Quarter': [0, 11000, 11000, 14000, 17000]}
b = pd.DataFrame(b)
print (b)
```

how do i replace values in dataframe 'a' with zero where dataframe 'b' is equal to zero?

so my desired output would be

```
a = {'Price': [0, 15, 20, 25, 30], 'Total': [0, 12000, 10000, 11000, 10000],
 'Previous Quarter': [0, 10000, 12000, 15000, 14000]}
a = pd.DataFrame(a)
print (a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution with `mask`:

```
a.mask(b==0,0)
```

EDIT: looking at the timings:

```
In [33]: %timeit a.mask(b==0,0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.47 ms per loop

In [34]: %timeit a[b==0] = 0
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.49 ms per loop

In [35]: %timeit a.where(b!=0, b)
100 loops, best of 3: 1.82 ms per loop

In [36]: %timeit a.where(b!=0, 0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.37 ms per loop
```

Comment: mask is not doing to be faster as it's a function calling where in the source code. the answer might be misleading here: the reason why where statement is slower here is because I use `b` as the alternative argument. `where(b!=0, 0)` will have the best timing

Comment: @Boud thanks for the comment, I'm editing the answer.

Answer (score 3):

As they have the same index, this works:

```
a[b==0] = 0
```

Another style to write it:

```
a.where(b!=0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you're new to python here is a very basic solution without list comprehensions:

```
for key,val in a.items():
    for i in range(len(val)):
        if b[key][i] == 0:
            a[key][i] = 0
```

Output:

```
   Previous Quarter  Price  Total
0                 0      0      0
1             10000     15  12000
2             12000     20  10000
3             15000     25  11000
4             14000     30  10000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for col in a.columns:

    for index in a.index:

        if b.loc[index,col] == 0:

            a.loc[index,col] = b.loc[index,col]
```

hope that helps!